# html javascript simple swap player turn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm studying for a excesice of a Based-Turn Game and what would like to have is  **a swap player turn function in JS.**

I have a idea what I need but I donno how to do, I need it as simple as possible. I just need a ***div to show who's turn*** and a ***button to changes turn***.

I just found very old examples and I bet there are new solutions as simple as I want :)

part of code:

```
<SCRIPT name = "JavaScript">
function variables(){
    t = 1;
    return;
    whogoesnow = "Turn player 1"
}

function win(){ if (...) alert ("player 1: won the game !!!"); 
if (...) alert ("player 1: won the game !!!");}

function turnchange(t){
  if (change == 1)  {
    if (t == 0){
        t = 1;
        whogoesnow = "turn: player " + 1
    }
    else {
        t = 0;
    whogoesnow = "turn: player " + 2
    }

  }
  else {
    t = t;
  }
  change = 1  
  return (t); 
}
<script>
<SCRIPT name = "JavaScript">
variables();
</SCRIPT>

FORM>
<input type = "button" name = "whoseturn"  value = "Turn: player 1">
```

I hope it can give an ideia what I need, i accept anything like links, others sources, etc.

since now, thks for reading this and leave a help :D

Comment: do you want a js or css solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('#turn').toggleClass('a');
});
```

```css
#turn .turn_a{display:none}
#turn.a .turn_a{display:block}
#turn.a .turn_b{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="turn">
    <div class="turn_a">Player A</div>
    <div class="turn_b">Player B</div>
</div>
<button id="button">Change turn</button>
```

Comment: oooh thanks, you rox buddy :D it's a very simple code and u did much for me :D